# Iterating through user options and assigning them to the object instance in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

let's say I have this class in CoffeeScript:

```
class Human
   constructor: ( options ) ->
       if options 
           for property of options
               opts[ property ] = options[ property ]

   printName: ->
       console.log 'My name is ' + opts.name

   opts =
       name: 'foo'
```

If I was to print out the name property across multiple instances of the object, I would always get the same value:

```
a = new Human({name: 'bob'})
b = new Human({name: 'john'})

// a.printName() -> john
// b.printName() -> john
```

But I want to save the values for each instance individually, like this:

```
// a.printName() -> bob
// b.printName() -> john
```

Now I know I have to use `this.name`, but how would I accomplish that using a method to iterate through a long list of values and assigning them to the object instance? I don't want to pollute the constructor like this

```
constructor: ( @name, @surname, @age, ... )
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
class Human
   constructor: ( options ) ->
       @opts = default_ops
       if options 
           for property of options
               @opts[ property ] = options[ property ]

   printName: ->
       console.log 'My name is ' + @opts.name

   default_ops =
       name: 'foo'
```

Comment: If you pass @opts as a parameter to the constructor, it does indeed work! Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer! Please look closely to the variable declarations. You do not need to pass `@opts` to anything.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the output is always 'John'. Isn't the prototype shared by all instances?

Comment: This doesn't look quite right to me (knowing JS and not CoffeScript).  Defining opts on the prototype will mean it is shared across instances, hence the original problem of always returning 'John' remains.  I think you want `this.opts = {}` on the line below `constructor: ( options ) ->`, to create it as an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, passing the object as parameter to the constructor as reference works. Thanks to Amber for the heads up.

```
class Human
   constructor: ( @opts, options ) ->
       if options 
           for property of options
               @opts[ property ] = options[ property ]

   printName: ->
       console.log 'My name is ' + @opts.name

   @opts =
       name: 'foo'
```

Comment: That why you will have no default value for your `name` attribute. `c = new Human(); c.printName()` will cause an error.

Comment: You should remove the last two lines since they are redundant (more locally-scoped `@ops` is found first).  Also, using the `@ops` argument is a bit of a hacky work-around since it instantiates an instance variable from the argument's value.  You may as well just define the instance variable yourself and drop the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it very easy and readable way using a little help from `underscore` (or any other lib that provides `extend`-like functionality):

```
class Human
  DEFAULTS:
    name: 'default name'

  constructor: (opts = {}) ->
    @opts = _.extend {}, @DEFAULTS, opts

  printName: ->
    console.log 'My name is ' + @opts.name
```

BTW you can attach props directly to the instance:

```
class Human
  DEFAULTS:
    name: 'default name'

  constructor: (opts = {}) ->
    _.extend @, @DEFAULTS, opts

  printName: ->
    console.log 'My name is ' + @name
```